# CameraX RuntimeException lock buffer failed for format 0x21

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

We recently implemented CameraX to take images instead of using the device camera. Since the time we rolled out this feature in our app, we are seeing the following error. Can someone help debug this issue? I have tried googling this error but could not find any resources online.

```
RuntimeException lock buffer failed for format 0x21    
        android.media.ImageReader$SurfaceImage in nativeCreatePlanes
        android.media.ImageReader$SurfaceImage in getPlanes at line 1004
        androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageProxy in <init> at line 51
        androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy in acquireNextImage at line 102
        androidx.camera.core.MetadataImageReader in imageIncoming at line 322
```

Comment: 0x21 does not match any format in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat or  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat. Does this happen on a specific device model?

Comment: Crash happens on all these devices SM-A025U1,Stratus_C7,S6303L,Z22,SM-A025A,SM-A015A,SM-S124DL,N5502L,SM-A115W,SM-A025M,SM-A015V,moto g play - 2023,V23,SM-A115AP,Note 6T,SM-A115U1,moto g pure